# Laravel 5.2 Fresh Install on Homestead rev-manifest.json Error Not Found

Tags: homestead, laravel-5

I'm new to Homestead, but not Laravel. I went through the process of setting up my new install, and was able to see the homepage welcome message.

Then I tried to enable authentication for user logins by running:

> php artisan make:auth

This has worked for me outside of Homestead, but in this environment that starts the web page throwing the following error:

> public/build/rev-manifest.json): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory

I've looked inside public, and there is no build folder. Should I create it? If I should create the json file, what should I put inside? And, more importantly, why am I getting this error in general?

Help appreciate!

Comment: It seems to be a bug with gulp, respectively gulp-rev and laravel 5.2. After `php artisan make:auth` you have to run `npm install` to install some dependencies and after that `gulp` to create the asset files. It should then create build/rev-manifest.json in your public folder, which isn't the case with laravel 5.2. There's already an [open issue](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/391) in the repository of elixir.

It's not really a solution but you can comment out the content of the function elixir in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php to get at running again

Comment: This worked for me as a temporary fix

Comment: http://webmonkeys.io/threads/tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-laravel-5-2-part-1-setting-up-laravel-5-2.35/ helped a lot

Comment: I am having the same problems months later.... will this ever get fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` then `gulp`, to build your assets.

Otherwise you have to go to your master layout and delete Elixir helper calls ([credit](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/524-makeauth-causes-failure/replies/125384)):

`<!-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> -->`

`<!-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> -->`